# SQL Server 2014 queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, flags

I have a requirement where I have to check for records and if the record is present for both of the values, then flag is set to 0 and if it is present for only one value then flag is 1.

For example:

```
ID     Value
 1   'Season16'
 2   'Season16'
 2   'Season15'
 3   'Season15'
 3   'Season15'
 4   'Season16'
```

Now I want,

```
ID Flag
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   1
```

I.e. If ID has both Season16 and Season 15 then Flag is 0 else 1.

Can you guys pour in your thoughts?

Comment: I'd suggest a `select` query...

Comment: Will it always be just those two values (Season15 and Season16)?

Comment: Nope. It can be many seasons.. But I have to select Value= Max(Season) and  Value <> Max(Season)-1. I am somehow able to get the max and previous values. but unable to set the flag.

Comment: @chits The data for ID 3 has a 0, but ID 3 has Season15 twice and no Season16.  Should this be a 1 or was one of the Season15 supposed to be a Season16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very specific to your table structure and the possible number of seasons, but this is one way:

```
select 
    Id,
    case 
        when count(1) > 1 then 0 
        else 1
    end Flag
from MyTable
group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using multiple CTEs.  The first two build up the tables for each specific reason.  The final select will return all of the IDs with the flag set if there were both Seasons in the value list.

```
WITH CTE16 AS (SELECT * FROM @myTable WHERE Value = 'Season16'),
CTE15 AS (SELECT * FROM @myTable WHERE Value = 'Season15')

SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, 
       CASE WHEN B.Flag IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [Flag]
FROM @myTable A LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT A.ID, 1 [Flag] 
                                 FROM CTE16 A INNER JOIN CTE15 B 
                                         ON A.ID = B.ID) B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case when statement.   Hopefully this will answer your question.  You could help everyone by giving a little more info about your table.

```
Select 
    Value1, value2, 
    Case when value1 = value2 then 0 else 1 end as Flag 
from Values_Table
```